# how to maintain session state in restful webservics in cakephp?

Tags: php, web-services, session, cakephp, rest

i have develop **RESTful** web service in **cakephp** .
i am using **http GET** and **POST** method and sending request in form of **JSON**.
there is a scenario where i want to maintain session for particular user so i can track it.

on **server side** i maintain a **session** but it is not working

```
$game_session_id = $this->Session->read('game_session_id');
$leader_game_id = $this->Session->read('gameid')
```

i have to maintain session for web services .

Comment: did you write to the session before reading?

Comment: FYI: RESTful APIs should be stateless. Maintaining user sessions within the API violates this.

Comment: KTastrophy is right, see this topic response : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3105337/1252290