# HTTP request method with no data

Tags: web-services, http

I have a REST endpoint in my application that takes no data and returns no data.
The endpoint is clearing out some data I previously stored in the user's session. I don't need to send or receive data from the client -- just hit the endpoint.

I currently allow the endpoint to only receive HTTP POST requests.

Is there a better HTTP request method than POST for this scenario? If so why?

Comment: does make sense to make a POST with no resource?

Comment: Some details about what your application and what your endpoint do would be helpful.

Comment: What you describe does not sound RESTful.  Typically POST is used to create a resource and the response is the representation of that resource.

Comment: just to give you an idea, take a look at the section 9.5 of http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

Comment: The endpoint is clearing out some data I previously stored in the user's session. I don't need to send or receive data from the client -- just hit the endpoint.

Comment: add it to the question description, it makes not really much sense to me because looks like you are building "logout" funcionalities over a RESOURCE oriented service..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is actually fine. `POST` doesn't necessarily need to create a resource. If it's modifying the client's session, it's ok in my book. For the return code, consider `204/No content`.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint is not actually ReSTful. Clearing out session data means your aren't transferring state on each request, see [If REST applications are supposed to be stateless, how do you manage sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105296/if-rest-applications-are-supposed-to-be-stateless-how-do-you-manage-sessions)