# how to handle custom exceptions/flashes messages in a RESTful API with Symfony2

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

Let's say I run a clothing web shop. I have an order form that my customers can place orders. A customer fills out their order for a t-shirt and submits the form. The problem is the t-shirt is out of stock.

This isn't a validation issue, because the order was valid, so i wouldn't create a custom validator.

I'm using the FOSRestBundle and trying to support both HTML and JSON. I'm also trying to accomplish a lot through domain events.

Here's my pseudo coded controller

```
class OrderController extends BaseOrderController
{
    public function createAssetAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->getOrderCreateForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            // should i wrap this in a try/catch?
            $this->dispatch(OrderEvents::PRE_CREATE, $event = new FormEvent($form, $form->getData()));

            // or check if the event is stopped and pull out an error message? 

            if ($order = $event->getData()) {

                $this->getOrderRepository()->persist($order);
                $this->dispatch(OrderEvents::POST_CREATE, new ResourceEvent($order));

                $view = $this->routeRedirectView('my_orders', array(), Codes::HTTP_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
                $view->setData(array('order' => $order));
                return $this->handleView($view);
            }
        }

        $view = $this->view($form)
            ->setTemplateVar('form')
            ->setTemplate('OrderBundle:Order:newOrder.html.twig');

        return $this->handleView($view);
    } 
}
```

I'm thinking i would check the inventory of the order in the `OrderEvents::PRE_CREATE` event. I don't know whether to throw an exception in an event listener if there is insufficient stock or stop the event propagation and add a message to the event.

If i threw an exception, i'd have to catch it in the controller so i could set the exception message as a flash message for an HTML request or just return the message directly for a JSON response.

If i did that, i'd have to wrap all event dispatching in the controller in try/catches, which seems wrong.

I've seen the LiipCacheControl bundle which converts flash messages to a cookie but that introduces state into my stateless REST API.

Anybody have suggestions?

Comment: I don't think exceptions should be used for something like this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/77361/998328

Comment: just add messages to the event objects? Because symfony bundles seem to use custom exceptions a lot https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/1f76020d41f7f5dd1e96a59eb88fe6756d58dbd3/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Cart/ItemResolver.php#L149

Comment: check this out concerning stateless: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3105337/998328 i think cookies would be fine

Comment: My view on Exceptions and when to use them is language and framework agnostic. Exceptions are just that: _Exceptions_ .. They're a way of expressing unexpected or unintended results.