# Codeigniter API session

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, session

Am writing an api for IOS application
I have some concerns about handling session for the IOS application

When a user login from iphone, I need to pass the session id as login response and use that session id 
in further api calls for validating the user,

What I have done in my api controller is get the session id and save it to session array along with user details and pass the session id as response

```
  $session = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
        $user_array = array(

     'email' => $user->email,     
       'session_id'=>$session
                   );
      $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $user_array);

     $output = array(
                            'code'=>200,                            
                            'user'=>$user,
                            'session_id'=>$session
                   );
                   $this->output
                       ->set_content_type('application/json')
                       ->set_output(json_encode($output));
```

For the further api calls, I will get the session_id as a parameter,

I checked its a valid section or not using the following. code

```
 $session_id =  $this->input->get('session_id', TRUE);
        if($session_id){
            if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
                $user =  $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                 if($user['session_id'] == $session_id){
              // valid session
}
```

This worked well when tested with postman.

But am not sure , this is the correct way to handle session with API calls.

Will the same work when run from the IOS application?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are using a REST api method which is stateless, So session will not get maintained while calling from IOS application. Every call you make from the app will have a new session.

You have to use SOAP as a web service if you really need session to be maintained while API call.

For more information please check on [If REST applications are supposed to be stateless, how do you manage sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105296/if-rest-applications-are-supposed-to-be-stateless-how-do-you-manage-sessions)