# How to deal with GET request and (not to) changing the application state?

Tags: rest, http, http-verbs, idempotent

This is a generic question about GET method.

Imagine I need to store the last pagination size selected by the user:

```
+-------------+   +-------------+    +--------------------+    +----------+
| Size change |-> | GET request | -> | Server store pref. | -> | Response | 
+-------------+   +-------------+    +--------------------+    +----------+
```

Browsing a list of products is of course a GET request and changing the paging size is a GET request too (we change only the `size` parameter):

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/catalog/browse/size=10&page=1">size 10</a></li>
    <li><a href="/catalog/browse/size=25&page=1">size 25</a></li>
    <li><a href="/catalog/browse/size=50&page=1">size 50</a></li>
</ul>
```

Every time the **user changes the size** I need to **store the new size** in my backend.

How to deal the the fact the GET should not change the state? Issuing a query (thus **changing the state** of the application) fees so wrong to me. Is there any alternative?

> GET Requests a representation of the specified resource. Requests
>   using GET should only retrieve data and should have no other effect.

Comment: Why do you need to store the new size in your backend? Isn't the information you're given in the URL (page number and size) enough to return the correct result?

Comment: @Pekka웃 because the system should remember the last selected paging size for each user. So next time you login the pref. is restored.

Comment: How would storing the size make it non-idempotent? If I set the size to 50 twice, the size will be set to 50, just as if I set the size once. So it's idempotent. It wouldn't be idempotent if, for example, you incremented the size. Because incrementing twice doesn't lead to the same result as incrementing once.

Comment: @JBNizet idempotent in the sense that application state should change with A GET request.

Comment: @gremo that's the problem. Idempotent doesn't mean that state can't change. That's what you **think** it means.

Comment: @JBNizet so changing the state with a GET request is allowed in the sense of REST? Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: That's not what he said. It's not really RESTful to have a per-user page size setting (implying some sort of session in the background). It seems more correct to simply always pass a page number and page size...

Comment: @Pekka웃 i slightly changed the question to reflect what I really mean.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here about what REST is. A RESTful API by definition doesn't have a session connected to the requesting user in which something like a preferred page size can be stored. Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105296/if-rest-applications-are-supposed-to-be-stateless-how-do-you-manage-sessions

Comment: I disagree with Pekka. Returning a reponse that depends on who is sending the request is perfectly acceptable. And a server can have state, including state that is related to the connected user. I'm just saying that changing state as part of a GET request is perfectly valid, as long as it's idempotent. And it is in this case.