# REST Shopping cart

Tags: rest

Can a shopping cart be implemented using REST architecture constraints?

I would like to focus my question with respect to session state. In a typical MVC application implementing a shopping cart, it most likely, session object will be managed in session, shopping cart as a list of products.

How would this same shopping cart be managed in if the application had followed REST architecture. One of the REST constraints is state management is  responsibility of clients.

Should a shopping cart and it's progress be managed by client? Any examples? Any disadvantages of managing state in client with respect to a simple shopping cart or any other enterprise applications?

Comment: You should take a look at the defacto Hello World of REST (RestBucks Coffee Shop).

Comment: You're conflating the state of the session in the HTTP sense of the term, and a "session" global object which is an artifact provided by server-side frameworks.

Comment: I would like to clarify...shopping cart , of-course will be persisted to database after shopping is complete, question is not that basic. My question is with respect to 4th REST constraint which is Communicate stateless or in other words there is no client session data stored on the server. And given that, where will shopping cart be store client? That question is clarified below in answers. Thanks.

Comment: @SatBobbi The client won't store any information about the shopping cart at any time. All the information related to the shopping cart will be stored in the server.

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin, the question was about , where will you manage "the shopping cart" until user completes shopping, as it could span any where from half an an hour to an hour before User finishes shopping and finally submit the shopping cart. User is adding / removing products to this shopping cart during this time.The question was not about where will you ultimately persist shopping cart. You may have not understood my question and probably answers below. I consider this question is answered do no have enough reputation to bump up answers.

Answer (score 25):

There is nothing wrong with storing the shopping cart as a resource on the server.  It is *session state* that should be stored on the client.  https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3

In order to be stateless, your shopping-cart URI should be able to identify a unique cart without needing to rely on any session information.

For example, `/shopping-cart` is probably not sufficient unless there will only ever be one shopping cart throughout your application.

Likely, there will be at least one cart per user.  So, you could use something like `/user/1234/shopping-cart` or `/shopping-cart?userID=1234`.

Even more likely, you will probably need to have multiple shopping-carts per user.  So, you will want to give your carts a unique ID like `/user/1234/shopping-cart/5678` or just `/shopping-cart/5678`.

The point is, everything needed to process the request should be in the request.

Comment: Thanks , yes it makes sense to make shopping cart an addressable resource on server , most likely along the lines of /purchase-order/shopping-cart

Comment: I have no idea why someone downvoted this. It is the most accurate answer so far IMO. Never forget that REST describes what happens in the Web space, not in the realm of the application.

Comment: I agree with your answer with respect to address-ability of shopping cart on server, leaving state on client. not enough reputation to bump up ur answer. thanks for answering. not sure what you mean by "REST describes what happens in the Web space, not in the realm of the application". thanks.

Comment: What if I want to support anonymous users in my web page? I want them to be able to add a few items, and checkout. What goes into user id in that case?

Comment: You probably don't need a user id in that case. I'd go with `/shopping-cart/5678`. Or you can generate a user id that's just used for the session. Or you can use a placeholder like `/user/anon/shopping-cart/5678`.

Comment: In this scenario, how would you identify the last, or most recently used, shopping cart?

Answer (score 11):

In REST applications, the *session state* is entirely managed by the client and the request must contain all the necessary information to be understood by the server. If the server requires authentication, for example, each request must contain the credentials.

The REST [stateless constraint](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3) is defined as the following:

> **5.1.3 Stateless**
>
> [...] each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is therefore kept entirely on the client. [...]

However, the stateless constraint *doesn't mean the server shouldn't store any data*.

In applications which the *session state* is managed by the server, it's a common approach storing the shopping cart data in the HTTP session. But a shopping cart is not a *session state*. And, probably, it should not be entirely managed by the client.

In REST, a shopping cart, can be *a resource identified by a URL* such as `/shopping-cart` and operations can be performed over it. All the shopping cart data can be persisted to a database on the server.

[Any information that can be named can be a REST resource](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1), even a shopping cart:

> **5.2.1.1 Resources and Resource Identifiers**
>
> The key abstraction of information in REST is a *resource*. Any information that can be named can be a resource: a document or image, a temporal service (e.g. "today's weather in Los Angeles"), a collection of other resources, a non-virtual object (e.g. a person), and so on. In other words, any concept that might be the target of an author's hypertext reference must fit within the definition of a resource. A resource is a conceptual mapping to a set of entities, not the entity that corresponds to the mapping at any particular point in time. [...]

You can perform operations like these on your shopping cart:

- `GET /shopping-cart`: Get the shopping cart.
- `POST /shopping-cart`: Add an item to the shopping cart (sending some data with the item you are adding and the amount in the request body).
- `DELETE /shopping-cart/1`: Remove an item with id `1` from the shopping cart.
- `PATCH /shopping-cart`: Update the shopping cart (sending some data to be updated in the request body).
- `PUT /shopping-cart`: Replace the whole content of the shopping cart (sending some data with the content of your shopping cart in the request body).
- `DELETE /shopping-cart`: Remove the shopping cart
- `POST /shopping-cart/order`: Order the shopping cart content

So, observe the client won't store any information about the shopping cart at any time. All the information related to the shopping cart will be stored in the server.

---

For more information about REST, I do recommend reading the [chapter 5](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) of Roy T. Fielding's [dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm).

Comment: A user can take an 30 minutes to shop, then submit the shopping cart, seeing the total price, may decide to remove a few products from the cart, and then submit again, where is shopping cart being managed in such a client server interaction, in client code ? or is it persisted to a database based on your above explanation.

Comment: @SatBobbi All the shopping cart data will be persisted to a database in the server.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I like to disagree ... if we are saving state in database, it defeats the purpose of constraint. I think, we would not require a REST application for shopping cart ,any other web application would have solved the design. I was looking for an example if state is fully manged in client or what could be problems to fully manage state in state in client.

Comment: @SatBobbi Have a look at my updated answer. In REST, the *stateless* means the *session state* is managed by the client and every request must carry all the necessary information to be completed.

Comment: Mazzochi Molin, thanks for the reply. Question was not about persisting information ultimately. Question was about finding , if shopping cart would be stored and managed in client , until the operation is complete. And it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of confusion about REST exists because lots of people hear about REST constraints and think they are rules that are applied for no reason other than following the architecture as an end in itself.

The real question you should be asking is why the stateless constraint exists in REST, and what advantages do you get from following it. Keep in mind that REST is an architectural style intended for long-term evolution of large-scale distributed systems. You simply won't have the problems REST is supposed to solve in a small-scale application where a single database holds all your information.

> The stateless constraint induces the property of visibility,
>   reliability and scalability. Visibility is improved
>   because a monitoring system does not have to look beyond a single
>   request datum in order to determine the full nature of the request.
>   Reliability is improved because it eases the task of recovering from
>   partial failures. Scalability is improved because not having to
>   store state between requests allows the server component to quickly
>   free resources, and further simplifies implementation because the
>   server doesn't have to manage resource usage across requests.

So, being stateless means the client request should have all the information required to process it.

How important is visibility for you? Do you want to be able to see the whole contents of the shopping cart from the client request when you are debugging something, or are you ok with having to get that information from the databases?

How important is reliability? Do you have a large distributed system with several servers and databases, where that matters? If you have a large distributed system where the shopping cart information might be stored in different databases depending on the exact HTTP server that responded the request, if a server fails only another server from that group will be able to fulfill the request and finish the session, or a server from another group will force the client to restart the session. If all the information is contained in the request, then any server can do it.

How important is scalability? If you have a distributed system and you're storing shopping cart information on a single database, it becomes a funnel for all your requests and you lose scalability. If you store it on several databases, you lose reliability as explained above.

So, do you have ambitious long-term goals or is your application going to be large enough that you'll face the problems REST attempts to solve? If you'll always have a few servers and a single database, and you'll use it for every single request, then it doesn't matter if you go stateless or not. You can just have a `/shopping_cart` resource or something like that, add stuff to it with `POST` requests, and close or delete it when you're done.

If you'll have your data sharded across multiple databases, lots of HTTP servers responding requests, cache servers, etc, and you want to have the ability to provision capacity dynamically by setting up new servers as they're needed and removing them when load is reduced, then go full stateless and leave the shopping cart with the client.

Comment: Thank you!. Before asking I knew, that this constraint addresses scalability, so the same constraint addresses Reliability and visibility! So I like to leave the state with the client as envisioned application is large scale distributed application. I like to ask this follow up question, going by what I am reading, HTTP implementation of REST introduces short comings with "message level security and distributed transactions". Given that how do you justify your comment above "Keep in mind that REST is an architectural style intended for long-term evolution of large-scale distributed systems".

Answer (score 3):

I think somebody chose very unfortunate name for STATELESS concept and that's why the whole misunderstanding is caused. It's not about storing any kind of resources, but rather about the relationship between the client and the server.

Client: I'm sending you the "task list", which needs to be processed. Do your job.

Server: All right.. let me take the responsibility of processing the data that is important for you, in order to give you the proper response.

Meaning, the server is the "slave" of the client and has to forget about his "master" after each request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can,

Shopping cart data (added products) can be saved on the clients session, that ain't a problem.

Then once the user hits /checkout, the shopping cart should be persisted on the DB on the server. The key about rest is that every petition the client makes has to contain all data to identify himself, I suggest reading something about JWT or OAuth.

The app itself would work as any other shopping cart app you have seen, most of them do not persist the shopping cart in DB, just store it the clients session.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is where SPA(Single page applications) come into use since the SPA are loaded at once and after that the variables maintain the state and between components you can pass them if the components are hierarchical or otherwise as well you can use stores(like Redux) to maintain state.

However I feel ideally in real scenario you would want to persist the shopping cart for users for following scenarios:
1)User adds items to shopping cart but does not order.Later, maybe next day he wants to continue from where he left.So it should be persisted
2)User is logged on from multiple devices, say multiple family members using the same account. Here as well the cart should be in sync.