# Stateless authentication for Rest Api

Tags: php, rest, authentication, authorization, restful-authentication

searching for a good authentication method for my rest api i came a cross this :

**"What is stateless authentication?
Again, stateless means without state. But, how can we identify a user from a token without having any state on the server? Surprisingly, it’s very easy! just send all the data to the client.
So what would you store/send (send to client/network)? The most trivial example is an access token. Access tokens usually have a unique ID, an expiration date and the ID of the client that created it. To store this, you would just put this data into a JSON object, and encode it using base64."**

Now, having a self-contained token, you will need to make sure that nobody can manipulate the data. For this you should sign it using MAC algorithm or any other digital signature method available.

This is a little confusing for me , how can i validate the access token when the request comes(nothing stored to match it), but i find it a good idea and i want to implement it, any advice will be very helpful.

My rest api is very simple I receive every request to index.php , then i create new object with the request class to analyze every element of the request.

request class looks like this :

```
<?php

class Request {

public $url_elements;
public $verb;
public $parameters;

public function __construct() {
    $this->verb = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $this->url_elements = explode('/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);

    $this->parseIncomingParams();

    $this->format = 'json';
    if(isset($this->parameters['format'])) {
        $this->format = $this->parameters['format'];
    }
    return true;
}

public function parseIncomingParams() {
    $parameters = array();


    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
        parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $parameters);
    }


    $body = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $content_type = false;
    if(isset($_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'])) {
        $content_type = $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'];
    }
    switch($content_type) {
        case "application/json":
            $body_params = json_decode($body);
            if($body_params) {
                foreach($body_params as $param_name => $param_value) {
                    $parameters[$param_name] = $param_value;
                }
            }
            $this->format = "json";
            break;
        case "application/x-www-form-urlencoded":
            parse_str($body, $postvars);
            foreach($postvars as $field => $value) {
                $parameters[$field] = $value;

            }
            $this->format = "html";
            break;
        default:

            break;
    }
    $this->parameters = $parameters;
  }
 }
?>
```

After this i proceed with the proper controller that is the first element after index.php/

Thank you very much for your time and sorry if the question is not very clear as i am new to rest :/

Comment: Stateless authentication means that you do not initiate a session with the client. Basically they send you POST data with `username` and `password` variables. With this information you authenticate them against the database and allow/disallow the requested action. In addition to `username`/`password`, the request might also contain `action=delete_user` along with `user_id=9001`. If I misunderstood something about your question, please let me know.

Comment: I agree with you , but i don't understand the part "send all data to the client".

Comment: Have you visited jwt.io already? It's basically all what you need, you can use it for almost every language and the website explains quite well how it works exactly. It's completely stateless. The implementation allows you to create a secret key server side, which is used to decrypt the request. The request contains information like userid, action, url etc. Decryption only succeeds when the information is not manipulated, of course. You cannot manipulate the data without knowing the key, which is saved securely serverside.

Comment: @ErikvandeVen i am not sure if i visited it i have search so much on google today that i don't  know :P :P ill take a look asap .thank you very much

Comment: @ErikvandeVen yes i have seen it before ill take a deeper look at it and see if i can implement it. thank you again

Comment: @KlidiSpiro you are welcome. Implementation in NodeJS took minutes, so I guess the PHP version shouldn't be that hard either. I use it for almost everything: activation links which I send by mail and such, works great.

Comment: @KlidiSpiro I see, I think I now understand what you are trying to achieve from a technical perspective but would you be able to elaborate on the high-level goal you are trying to achieve? Will this be used for username verification via email link-clicking or are you implementing and API which people/servers can connect to and retrieve data?

Comment: If you're new to REST, maybe you should be asking what problem the stateless constraint attempts to solve and if you really need it. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33787625/1202421

Comment: @PedroWerneck thank you very much ill take a look at it