# get Json Data From URL in C#

Tags: json, c#-4.0

I am new to json i want get json data from a link, here from web search i have written code

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = @"http://hololens5.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/INTERSHOP/web/WFS/inSPIRED-inTRONICS_Business-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProduct-Start?SKU=1599925&CategoryName=151&CatalogID=Computers";
        using (WebClient wc=new WebClient())
        {
                json = wc.DownloadString(url);
        }

        string path = @"ouptputfileJSON.json";

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(json);
            }
        }
    }
```

When i execute this code i'm getting output in html page. how to get in json data of select product in the link provided

Answer (score 1):

Here is the rest endpoint you are looking for:

```
http://hololens5.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/INTERSHOP/rest/WFS/inSPIRED-
inTRONICS_Business-Site/-;loc=en_US;cur=USD/products/1599925
```

Documentation about other rest endpoints:
https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/T27711

Comment: Hi @Willem Evertse, using above intershop links i have created ShoppingCart system in Unity following this format [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008871/url-design-restful-api). this [Web Site](http://hololens5.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/INTERSHOP/web/WFS/inSPIRED-inTRONICS_Business-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProduct-Start?SKU=1599925&CategoryName=151&CatalogID=Computers) link was running  website. when i add product to cart its not showing cart in the website

Comment: i'm not sure i understand the question, but if u want to use the basket rest api of intershop you need to follow their flow, not create your own. See this https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/260Q29 for details on how to integrate with intershop using the rest apis. If you have questions about intershop post using the intershop tag and the guys will help u out.

Answer (score 0):

Because

> http://hololens5.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/INTERSHOP/web/WFS/inSPIRED-inTRONICS_Business-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProduct-Start?SKU=1599925&CategoryName=151&CatalogID=Computers
>
> Is webpage and not API endpoint so you need to find proper endpoint from where you want to get data

**Once you get Proper Endpoint you can use below**

Here is an example how you can use httpclient to make a request

```
static void Main()
{
    Task t = new Task(DownloadPageAsync);
    t.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Downloading page...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async void DownloadPageAsync()
{
    // ... Endpoint
    string page = "request URL";

    // ... Use HttpClient.
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page))
    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
    {
        // ... Read the string.
        string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say i am really starter as a developer so please tell me how could i find endpoint or how to create a Api endpoint

Comment: Is it your own website?

Comment: Here is the good tutorial for making web APIs in .net http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/test-web-api

Comment: You said that their is no proper end point, that means .html or .aspx or anything else should give there

Comment: when you make a get call to .aspx or .html page it'll always give you html data because that's what they are meant to do. on the other hand, API will give you JSON/XML or any other format, based on request and configuration because that's what they do. so you can't expect JSON from aspx or html

Comment: so to get the json data i have to implement this api and i need to access website code

Comment: Yes exactly that's why i asked is it your website in first place