# Spring boot ecommerce with jwt + sessions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, session, jwt, e-commerce

My app is curently secured with jwt tokens, and i want implement cart functions etc....
So im thinking about..
When headers contains valid jwt, there will be database cart..
Othervise i will use session to store cart..
But can i set some condition of creating session? i know there is

```
http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

Or what aproach would you recommend me?

Mayby storing product names and quantity in local storage, and sending it within header? Or should entire website be done with sessions?

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33786421/rest-shopping-cart .I think it is totally doable without Session. Besides, those information are for Spring Security, not for everything in Spring. You could combine jwt authentication without session and the cart in the session, but I think you loose the interest of doing a sessionless app.

Comment: If you are using spring boot, and you only need the session, you can simply use the built-in spring security for that. This will not use JWT. I have a project to demostrate that https://github.com/ytbryan/summerboot