# Express and redis session keeps returning undefined

Tags: node.js, session, express, node-redis

I've been having problems trying to access stored session values! Once I've set the values and try access them from a new route, I get `undefined`! So basically I've got a l`ogin (POST)` and in that request I set the session data, and then I have a `show user details (POST)` where I try and access the session data I've just stored.

#### Setup

```
// Setup express and needed modules #############################################
    var express = require('express'),
        session = require('express-session'),
        cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
        redis = require("redis"),
        redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session),
        bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var client = redis.createClient(), //CREATE REDIS CLIENT
    app = express();

// Setup app
app.use(cookieParser('yoursecretcode'));
app.use(session(
    {
        secret: 'x', 
        store: new redisStore({
            port: 6379, 
            client: client 
        }),
        saveUninitialized: true, // don't create session until something stored,
        resave: false // don't save session if unmodified
    }
));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy
```

So as you've seen my setup, you know I'm using *express sessions* and *Redis*. Below is where I'm setting the session values! If I print out the session values here it works, but then If I try and access the session data in another route it returns undefined.

#### Routes

I send a http post request and set the session data:

```
router.route('/login/').post(function(req, res) {
        req.session.userId = req.body.uId;
        req.session.name = req.body.uName;
        // THIS PRINTS OUT IF I TRY AND ACCESS THE SESSION DATA HERE
        console.log("THIS PRINTS OUT --> " + req.session.name);
 });
```

So now that the session values have been set, I can go access them right, no, I get undefined each time I try and log them out.

```
router.route('/user/printoutuserdetails').post(function(req, res) {
        // THESE RETURN UNDEFINED
        console.log(req.session.userId);
        console.log(req.session.uName);
        console.log("THIS PRINTS OUT --> " + req.session.name);
 });
```

Does anyone have any idea what's happening? I've tried everything and looked everywhere and can't seem to find a way to get it to work!

#### Solved:

The reason this wasn't was because you're not suppose to use sessions when using a RESTFUL api.

Comment: Did you try `req.session.save()` in `/login` router to store the session?

Comment: Unfortunately `.save()` didn't work :\ @NguyenSyThanhSon

Comment: Did you try removing `app.use(cookieParser('yoursecretcode'));`? I don't think that's needed anymore for `express-session`.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work @mscdex - I also verified that the data is being stored in my redis database

Comment: Did you also delete the cookies already set by your app after you removed that middleware?

Comment: Is the client calling `/login/` router via `ajax`?

Comment: Yes! I've been testing the routes using POSTMAN (sends http requests like curl) @NguyenSyThanhSon

Comment: So you should use Access Token for authorization. With restful api, you are not able to use session. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-of-session-management-in-REST-architecture or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105296/if-rest-applications-are-supposed-to-be-stateless-how-do-you-manage-sessions

Comment: Ahhhhh, thanks so much! @NguyenSyThanhSon

Comment: Is this question solved?