# Why I'm getting always a new session in SparkJava?

Tags: session-cookies, spark-java

I have a SparkJava api filter that is called by my client every 30 seconds.

```
before("/app/*", {
    req, _ ->
    println(req.session().attributes().size)
    println(req.session().id())
    println(req.session().isNew)
    req.session().attribute("test", "test")
})
```

The result is:

```
0
node0r3ulllnarwq5i62o2wcpxmu25
true
0
node0i0morm89ftci1tntiu38p8l5026
true
0
node09n12ooeo0t34wkpaqfhbbou227
true
```

You can see above, the session id is always different.
Why the session is always a new session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stupidly mistaken, but the behavior is correct. REST is stateless and has no session.

There is a good explanation: 
[If REST applications are supposed to be stateless, how do you manage sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105296/if-rest-applications-are-supposed-to-be-stateless-how-do-you-manage-sessions)

Comment: If you answered your own question you should probably mark the question as answered :)