# Can I use a session identifier in a REST API?

Tags: rest, session-state, stateless

I need to develop a client that communicates with a server via a REST API.
At the moment, the log in is going on like this:

- The client sends a connection request via an URL of this type:

URL:

```
/api/username/password/
```

- The server returns a session identifier:

JSON:

```
{
  "request_status": "OK",
  "token": "1234567890"
}
```

- Then, the client have to send this token in every futures requests like this:

URL:

```
/api/1234567890/...
```

I can't figure out whether this operation complies with the stateless principle of the REST standard.
I thought it didn't respect the stateless principle, but I can't explain it to myself clearly and [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3105337/6113711) in [another StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105296/if-rest-applications-are-supposed-to-be-stateless-how-do-you-manage-sessions) (especially at the end where he talks about authentication) put me in doubt.

Comment: The fact that you have a server-side session makes the server stateful, thereby "RESTless".

Comment: Ok, thank you for that clarification.