# I am stuck at Unable to set cookie or session Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-8, session-cookies

None of the below methods is setting cookie. i tried defining the route in `Routes/api.php` also.And in case of session,`dd(session()->get('access_token'));` inside the `session_login()` method immaediately after setting session gives data.But in `index()` method, it gives null data. I am able to use the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie` facade only, when using the direct facade `use cookie;` it shows error `undefined type`.So, i couldn't try the `cookie::queue()`similarly for session also, not able to try with `use session`  facade. that's why i've commented it in the below code.How can i fix this? i've already gone through many links in internet. Any help is much appreciated.

**controller**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
//use Cookie;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
//use Session;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function getCookie(Request $request){
        $value = $request->cookie('access_token');
        return $value;
     }
      public function login(Request $request)
    {
       $response = new Response();
       $response->withCookie(cookie('access_token','abcd',60));

       //Cookie::queue('access_token','abcd',60);

      //Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('access_token','abcd',60));  --shows error Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie::queue() 

       return redirect('/getCookie');
    }
   public function session_login(Request $request)
     {
       session(['access_token'=>$token]);
       return redirect('/');
     }
     public function index()
     {
       return session()->get('access_token');
     }
}
```

**Routes/web.php**

```
Route::post('/signin', [AuthController::class,'login']);
Route::get('/getCookie',[AuthController::class,'getCookie']);
Route::get('/',[AuthController::class,'index']);
```

**Config/session.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),  //also tried adding false to this
    'http_only' => true,
    'same_site' => 'lax',
];
```

**.env file**

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file       //tried changing this to database also
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=mydomain.com
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
```

Comment: (Unrelated) fyi: Api routes in Laravel are stateless, they don't use cookies/sessions

Comment: @brombeer ok.Can you tell why i can't get the session value or y  i can't set the cookie?

Comment: Another fyi: the _facade_ for cookie is `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie`. You don't need those if you use `$request->session()` or `$request->cookie()`

Comment: @brombeer i know that. But that's not the error here, know?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Cookie` facade and `Cookie::queue()` to set and `Cookie::get()` to get cookie values.

Stripped down (working) version of your controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function getCookie()
    {
        $value = Cookie::get('access_token');
        return $value;
    }

    public function login()
    {
        Cookie::queue('access_token', 'abcd', 600);
        return redirect('/getCookie');
    }

}
```

Head to `/signin`, a cookie `access_token` will be set with the value `abcd`. You'll be redirected to `/getCookie`, which will output `abcd`.

Routes used (`routes/web.php`):

```
Route::get('/signin', [AuthController::class,'login']);
Route::get('/getCookie',[AuthController::class,'getCookie']);
```

Edit: for session access use this Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function getSession()
    {
        $value = session('access_token');
        return $value;
    }

    public function login()
    {
        session(['access_token' => 'abcde']);
        return redirect('/getSession');
    }

}
```

with these routes:

```
Route::get('/signin', [App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::get('/getSession', [App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'getSession']);
```

Again, head to `/signin`, a session will be set and you'll be redirected to `/getSession`, which prints out `abcde`.

Comment: no. it's not returning any  value still

Comment: It does on my end, I tested it before posting (Linux, Laravel Framework 8.83.0). Did you enable cookies in your browser? Does a cookie show up in your browsers DevTools? Any cookie-blocker-addons running in your browser? Any errors/notices in your DevTools console about cookies? How do you serve your project? Apache? `php artisan serve`?

Comment: @no errors in console. running server with `php artisan serve`. I can see laravel's default cookies are beings stored in the local storage.If cookies are not enabled, how it happens? And with `session->all()` , am able to get the laarvel default session.

Comment: But not getting the session i set

Comment: @user17189691 I edited my question and added a working controller using the session along with routes. Serving via `php artisan serve`. If this doesn't work for you you might want to check your Laravel session settings, cookie settings in your browser or try a different browser

Comment: Cookies are stored in LocalStorage? That shouldn't be

Comment: i tried ur new answer also. it also not working for both cookies & session.It was a typo in my last comment. cookies are not stored in local storage. it's stored under the cookies folder of storage section in application tab.

Comment: I've updated the original question body with my session settings. please have a look .

Answer (score 0):

In `App\Http\Kernel`:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

In `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`:

```
 $this->routes(function () {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    });
```

In `RouteServiceProvider` `web.php` uses `web` middlewareGroup and `api.php` uses `api` middlewareGroup. So, `web` middlewareGroup includes session and cookie middlewares, which are respond to work with them.

So, if you want to you use sessions and cookies in `api.php`, you need to add session and cookie middlewares to `api` middlewareGroup:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    ],
];
```

Comment: i've commented `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,` - this line in my kernal.Otherwise, it shows `419 page expired error` on form submission. except that, i tried this answer(it's also not working. brings Same situation mentioned in question )

Comment: Maybe this answer can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59037903/12503693