# 401 Unauthorized only occurring on some pages in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

Have created an app in Laravel 8, and have used the PHP artisan command "ui:auth" to create a login system, which works fine. However, when trying to use "auth()->check()" in other controllers, I get a 401 Unauthorised Error. This occurs both when logged in in the app, as in Postman.

My Controller that is having the issue:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Store;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class StoreController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show()
    {
        return auth()->user();
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using valid credentials?

Comment: In Postman API test tool, you also have to pass necessary auth tokens or cookies.

Comment: I presumed it wouldn't work in Postman anyway due to the lack of credentials, but when logging to the built-in Register/login system (created using PHP artisan UI:auth), and having the register/login controller calling auth()->user() or Auth::user() returns fine. So its just my "custom" pages that aren't able to access Auth::user() etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue ended up being resolved by updating /app/Http/Kernel.php and adding the following code:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

to `protected $middlewareGroups`

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59037485/how-to-get-sessions-working-in-laravel-api-routes Was referenced in solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

It should work for you. Try this:
Carefully enter the right credentials.

```
return Auth::user();
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's default authentication system is on session and you can not log in with postman.
To do this, you must use a passport or sanctum reader.
Then you have to go to "config/auth.php" and set the following values

```
'guards' => [
'web' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'users',
],

'api' => [
    'driver' => 'passport',
    'provider' => 'users',
],
```

],

You must use "api guards"

Read the link below

[Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport)